# Do I need permissions for app on sd card?

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, expo

I was wondering if I have to include permissions for the external storage in case the user moves the app on the SD card (Android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you need permission for the app on your sd card.

GO to the `settings` >> `App Management` >> `Installed apps` >> chose the app you want to move to your `SD card` >> open `storage` in-app `uses section` >> then change the app to internal to `Sd Card`. Then the Export window will be open and ask permission to access the sd card (Read Write Permission) >> Click on `Move`. Then Done Your app is transferred successfully.

if you are facing any issues enable the developer option then choose  option `F0rce to allow apps on external` in the `Application` section